# Failed to find the flaskblog error in flask

Tags: python, flask

[image: this is the error I am getting]I am trying to run flask first app.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello world!'
```

and I have also used `export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py`

But it is constantly getting the error

> Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "flaskblog". Use "FLASK_APP=flaskblog:name to specify one.

Comment: Can you post what you see when you run `python flaskblog.py`

Comment: Can you please post the output of the above command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run "`export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py`" from the directory where your source code exist.

After that, run "`flask run`".

I noticed that your export was done from a different directory.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the app.run which makes this a flask app. Change your flaskblog.py to the following

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The error in your screenshot is different from the one you posted earlier. Is the path you are importing from on the PYTHONPATH variable? Ensure you've set your PYTHONPATH to the src/ directory as well. Example export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/src"

Answer (score 0):

Remove this if you have (in this case, you do have):

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run()

Answer (score -1):

Yourre following the right steps. Just ensure that your hello.py file is saved with all the code correctly written. Save again and try again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
FLASK_APP=flaskblog:name
```

to specify one.